# Using shortcuts in Python in Linux

Tags: python, linux, terminal, shortcut

I would like to use a shortcuts in Python in Linux. A simle code below:

```
import os
os.system("eclipse &")#launching eclipse
os.system("ctrl+alt+t")#bad code - e.g. run a terminal
```

Line 3 is a bad code and I would like to know if there is a possibility to use shortcuts in Python.

Answer (score 0):

Keyboard shortcuts are basically tied to your GUI.  Just launch the terminal executable directly.  Pass the path to bash, sh, or whatever shell of your choice to `os.system` instead of trying to pass it the keyboard shortcut.